# How to render Backfacing Culling

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, normals

I have flipped normal of object, but unlucky, it didn't work in render. Is there way to fix it?

### This what I want:

[image: 1]

### But I got this in render:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

Two years late, but for reference :)

If you want to have backface culling in cycles you can use a material setup like this:

[image]

Which basically uses two materials, a diffuse one (or whichever one you want) and a transparent material (to cull backfacing surfaces). You just mix them using the backfacing output of the geometry node so that backfacing surfaces use the transparent material.